# Ubuntu 14.04 ethernet connection using graphical network manager

Tags: network-manager, ethernet

I am trying to connect Ubuntu 14.04 to the internet with an ethernet cable. I have turned wireless off. The cable works off a Windows laptop that I am using now. When I plug in the cable 'wired connection 1' appears but the symbol in the top right hand corner of the screen continues to cascade bars as though it is trying to establish a connection. Sometimes it will say 'wireless disconnected'. My problem, is possibly similar to [forum post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/586311/ethernet-connection-not-working). But it does not give a good description of how to graphically setup the connection. I include below frequently asked commands

```
anthony@anthony-VPCZ12V9E:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:be:d6:84:53  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:306 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:964 (964.0 B)  TX bytes:60085 (60.0 KB)
          Interrupt:18 Memory:d7800000-d7820000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:4500 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4500 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:340508 (340.5 KB)  TX bytes:340508 (340.5 KB)

anthony@anthony-VPCZ12V9E:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
anthony@anthony-VPCZ12V9E:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN


~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


anthony@anthony-VPCZ12V9E:~$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:be:d6:84:53  
          inet6 addr: fe80::224:beff:fed6:8453/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:452 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1028 (1.0 KB)  TX bytes:88628 (88.6 KB)
          Interrupt:18 Memory:d7800000-d7820000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:7206 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7206 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:545840 (545.8 KB)  TX bytes:545840 (545.8 KB)

anthony@anthony-VPCZ12V9E:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
anthony@anthony-VPCZ12V9E:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
```

To clarify either side of the tildes in my code paste are without cable plugged in (above tilde) and with cable below.

Below is q screenshot of what I see graphically

[image]

The following information may also help.

```
anthony@anthony-VPCZ12V9E:~$ uname -a
Linux anthony-VPCZ12V9E 3.13.0-48-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 12 11:16:18 UTC 2015 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
anthony@anthony-VPCZ12V9E:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82577LC Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10eb] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Sony Corporation Device [104d:905a]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
--
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 [8086:422c] (rev 35)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6200 2x2 AGN [8086:1301]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
anthony@anthony-VPCZ12V9E:~$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
btusb                  27580  0 
qcserial               17059  0 
usb_wwan               19733  1 qcserial
usbserial              38902  2 qcserial,usb_wwan
nls_iso8859_1          12617  0 
usb_storage            48417  0 
bbswitch               13615  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     45440  4 
rfcomm                 53664  0 
bnep                   18895  2 
bluetooth             342208  11 bnep,btusb,rfcomm
snd_hda_codec_realtek    59259  1 
arc4                   12536  2 
iwldvm                214950  0 
mac80211              546067  1 iwldvm
mxm_wmi                12893  0 
uvcvideo               71309  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      13048  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13170  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
intel_powerclamp       14239  0 
videobuf2_core         39258  1 uvcvideo
coretemp               13195  0 
videodev              108503  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
kvm                   388310  0 
snd_hda_intel          42794  5 
crc32_pclmul           12967  0 
snd_hda_codec         164067  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
aesni_intel            18156  0 
aes_i586               16995  1 aesni_intel
snd_hwdep              13272  1 snd_hda_codec
xts                    12749  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    13057  1 aesni_intel
snd_pcm                85501  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
gf128mul               14503  2 lrw,xts
ablk_helper            13357  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 15578  1 ablk_helper
snd_page_alloc         14230  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
joydev                 17101  0 
snd_rawmidi            25135  1 snd_seq_midi
serio_raw              13230  0 
intel_ips              18217  0 
snd_seq                55383  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
iwlwifi               152049  1 iwldvm
lpc_ich                16864  0 
snd_seq_device         14137  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              28584  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
cfg80211              409394  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm
i915                  710013  2 
nvidia               9704610  47 
snd                    60939  21 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
mac_hid                13037  0 
mei_me                 18195  0 
sony_laptop            44359  0 
drm_kms_helper         48868  1 i915
mei                    66737  1 mei_me
soundcore              12600  1 snd
drm                   244037  5 i915,drm_kms_helper,nvidia
video                  18903  1 i915
wmi                    18673  1 mxm_wmi
shpchp                 32128  0 
i2c_algo_bit           13197  1 i915
parport_pc             31981  0 
ppdev                  17391  0 
tpm_infineon           17164  0 
lp                     13299  0 
parport                40836  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
e1000e                223034  0 
sdhci_pci              18535  0 
ptp                    18445  1 e1000e
ahci                   25579  2 
sdhci                  37779  1 sdhci_pci
libahci                27214  1 ahci
psmouse                91357  0 
pps_core               18799  1 ptp
anthony@anthony-VPCZ12V9E:~$ cat /etc/r
rc0.d/        rc3.d/        rc6.d/        resolvconf/   rpc
rc1.d/        rc4.d/        rc.local      resolv.conf   rsyslog.conf
rc2.d/        rc5.d/        rcS.d/        rmt           rsyslog.d/
anthony@anthony-VPCZ12V9E:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
anthony@anthony-VPCZ12V9E:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
```

Comment: You can try running `dhclient eth0`. Graphical setup is in System Settings>Network.

Comment: will do. To clarify either side of the tildes in my code paste are without cable plugged in (above tilde) and with cable below.

Comment: @Sav-econ since comments can be deleted for any number of reasons it would be preferable to indicate that within your edit.

Comment: Is it worth setting up manually? In the past it has worked automatically, which I believe is called dhcp

Comment: i've tried to restart the network manager as said here http://askubuntu.com/a/489921/252173 but still no luck

Comment: Any suggestions, just to get ,me started would be really useful! thanks

Comment: I have also tried echo -e "nameserver 8.8.8.8\nnameserver 8.8.4.4" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf
sudo service network-manager restart also does not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command resolved the problem

```
echo -e "nameserver 8.8.8.8\nnameserver 8.8.4.4" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf
```

Then restart network-manager with the following command

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Then I restarted the computer for it to work.

Comment: Please may someone elaborate on what my problem was and why this resolves it.